# BOVPN on Firebox XTM 21 not connecting to Firebox X 500

Tags: vpn, firewall, firebox

I have set up a BOVPN on XTM 21 and it is not showing or connecting to the X500 on the other side.  I have looked at the traffic logs on both sides and there are no records of it even reaching the other end?  I have verified both static IP Address are correct.

Here is the setup: Credential Method: Preshared Key.  Verified the key. Mode: Aggressive.  Remote Gateway and Remote ID are the IP address of the remote site.  Authentication Alg.  SHA1-HMAC.  Encryption Alg. 3DES-CBC. No Enable TOS for IPSEC.  No Enable Perfect Forward Secrecy. Local network 192.168.2.0/24.  Remote Network 192.168.1.0/24.  I need some help and a second set of eyes trouble shooting this please!!!

Thanks for your assitance
msindle

Comment: To confirm, each site has a different subnet? Did you configure the routes on both fireboxes?

Comment: Yes both fireboxes have routes.  We rebooted the X500 (to our main facility) and it shows that there is a VPN tunnel available, but now it is showing inactive.  I'm rebooting the X21 now to see if it helps

Comment: Ok it took a few seconds, but rebooting both sides refreshed the boxes and it is working.

Comment: Awesome glad to hear it. Typically its the route configuration that gets you, because you need to add them in the Tunnel options, **not** the standard Network -> Routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting both fireboxes solved the problem